# SetDataSource of Excel Chart from Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, charts

I haven't been able to find any workable solution for this in a couple hours of searching, so here I go.

I am exporting some data from access to excel via vba, formatting the excel and moving worksheets around, and then generating a chart. When I was testing it all in an excel macro I was able to use the SetDataSource method to adjust the range, but when I moved over to Access it didn't like this method, and will throw a run-time error of 438, "Object doesn't support this property or method". Simplified code below.

```
Dim xl as Object, wb as Object
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With xl
    .Visible = False
    .displayalerts = False
    Set wb = .workbooks.Open(wbookpath)

    'formatting code that all works fine

    .Charts.Add
    'add was called from sheet 11, popped up before 11 and am moving to end
    .Sheets(11).move after:=.Sheets(12)
    With Charts(1)
        .SetSourceData .Range("Master!$A$1:$G$11")
        'other chart formatting code that all works fine
    End With

    .activeworkbook.Close (True)
    .Quit
End With
```

I have also tried changing the source, e.g.

```
.SetSourceData .Sheets("Master").Range("$A$1:$G$11")
```

changing where I call it from, e.g.

```
.Charts.Add
wb.Charts(1).SetSourceData .Range("Master!$A$1:$G$11")
With .Charts(1)
'rest of code
```

but it doesn't affect the error being thrown.

How can I get Access to adjust the source of my chart? If I can get this working then I would be able to go forward with making a slew of other charts as well.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax worked for me:

```
    With wb.Charts(1)
        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Master").Range("$A$1:$G$11")
        'other chart formatting code that all works fine
    End With
```

Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.setsourcedata